# Call a function defined in another function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can I call a function nested inside another function from the global scope in python3.2?

```
def func1():
    def func2():
        print("Hello")
        return
    return
```

Is ther a way to call func2() from outside func1()?

Comment: You're generating the `func2()` object only if `func1()` is called first. For the sake of decoupling these tightly bound `def` statements, I recommend always defining each function individually, then calling `func1()` as a wrapper around `func2()`.

Comment: @Sam What is the motivation ??

Comment: eyquem's answer works. It may not be elegant or recommended, but if you know what you are doing, you can use it. Much better than using the dunder attributes/methods etc.

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/closure

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, unless you return the function:

```
def func1():
    def func2():
        print("Hello")
    return func2

innerfunc = func1()
innerfunc()
```

or even

```
func1()()
```

Answer (score 11):

You **want** to use [@larsmans'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8457693/89391) solution, but theoretically you can cut yourself into the code object of the locally accessible `func1` and slice out the code object of `func2` and execute that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def func1():
    def func2():
        print("Hello")

# => co_consts is a tuple containing the literals used by the bytecode
print(func1.__code__.co_consts)
# => (None, <code object func2 at 0x100430c60, file "/tmp/8457669.py", line 4>)

exec(func1.__code__.co_consts[1])
# => prints 'Hello'
```

But again, this is **nothing for production code**.

Note: For a Python 2 version replace `__code__` with `func_code` (and import the `print_function` from the `__future__`).

Some further reading:

- http://web.archive.org/web/20081122090534/http://pyref.infogami.com/type-code
- http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec
- http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/2/1/exec-in-python/

Comment: +1 for sheer madness and audacity. While not fit for code you'll have to maintain, it's great to understand what happens under the hood (e.g. that functions are decoupled from their bytecode and that bytecode can be executed seperately).

Comment: @delnan _" it's great to understand what happens under the hood"_ Yes !

Answer (score 0):

```
def func1():
    def func2():
        global fudu
        fudu = func2
        print("Hello")
    func2()


func1()

fudu()

print 'fudu' in dir()
print 'func2' in dir()
```

result

```
Hello
Hello
True
False
```

Also:

```
def func1():
    global func2
    def func2():
        print("Hello")
    func2()


func1()

print 'func2' in dir()
func2()
```

result

```
Hello
True
Hello
```

What's the interest?

Comment: I think the reason your answer has been downvoted is that you put in lots of code with little explanation, and because your code is something of a hack, and because there is a [good solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8457693/89391) using functional programming techniques.

Comment: @Kazark Thank you. I wasn't aware of this impression given by a lack of explanation. On the contrary, I thought that it could be lighter for a reader not to have evident comments concerning so easy to understand codes. - "hack" appears to me as an excessive word for my codes - I didn't try to give a better answer than other ones, I showed other ways that may give to OP additional ideas and comprehension.

Comment: Okay, sorry for just calling it a hack; I should explain. Your code calls the inside function at definition, which is not called for in the spec. Also, the use of the `global` keyword could cause some people to frown on it.

Comment: This solution worked for me. It should not have been downvoted. Plus it should be the correct answer which is currently "No, you cannot do that".

Comment: @KeithPinson: In my case, I cannot return the inner function because it (the outer function) is already returning something. So it is not a good solution. eyquem's solution was perfect for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on eyquem's solution.

```
def func1():
    global func2  # put it in global scope
    def func2():
        print("Hello")
```

Now you can invoke func2 directly.

But func1() would have to be called before you can call func2() otherwise it will not have been defined yet.