# Calling a function in other module

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to call a function inside of an other module but i i always get the same error statement "module 'mat_import' has no attribute 'matread'".

After getting the "filename" and "button_pressed" value from the GUI I want to call matread inside of mat_import. The result should be that I have filename1 and button_pressed accessable inside of the main.py.

**The main.py:**

EDIT:To get "filename1" and "button_pressed" the function gui inside of GUI.py is called. This works and returns the filename to the main.py. After that i want to call matread inside of mat_import. The function matread should get the filename from the main.py and read the file. The outputs are the two variables "signals" and "signaldata".

```
import mat_import as mi
import GUI

filename1, button_pressed = GUI.gui()

if (button_pressed ==1):
    signals, signaldata = mi.matread
```

**The mat_import.py:**

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
import csv
import os
import main

filename1 = ""
global matread

def matread():
    #get signals and signaldata
    return signals, signaldata
```

Comment: you are not calling `matread`, did ou try `mi.matread()`

Comment: Yes, but the same error occures.

Comment: is matread defined globally? If it's defined inside another function, as it looks from your indentation, then it might not be in the mat_import module's global namespace. More information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457669/call-a-function-defined-in-another-function

Comment: @Jonas I can't see what's wrong with my code with this link. How am i supposed to define matread?

Comment: @Rainer see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, my best guess from your description of the problem and the indentation in your question is that matread() is defined within another function in the mat_import.py file. In order to make matread callable from main.py, you need to 1. define it as global and 2. execute the function that it is defined in. Alternatively, you can define matread() outside any other function, as I did with matread2 below. You can read more about variable scope here: https://matthew-brett.github.io/teaching/global_scope.html

mat_import.py:

```
def matread2():
        return "b"

def outer_func():
        global matread
        def matread(): return "a"
```

main.py:

```
import mat_import as mi

try:
        mi.matread()
except AttributeError as e:
        print(e)
mi.outer_func()
print mi.matread()

print mi.matread2()
```

Comment: Now i have the error "module 'mat_import' has no attribute 'outer_func'"

Comment: Can you post your entire mat_import file? @Rainer

Comment: @Rainer That was just an example not actually how your code will work

Comment: Well the code that I posted runs on its own, as described with the different filenames. If you have additional code, you'll have to integrate my code correctly. Also outer_func was a placeholder, I don't know what the outer function is called in your code.

Comment: @Jonas I'm sorry I can't post the entire mat_import file because I am not allowed to do this by the company i work for.

Comment: @Rainer Ok well, then just replace outer_func in my code by the name of the function within which matread() is defined in your mat_import.py file.

Comment: @Jonas I dont have an outer function. I only have the mat_import file with matread as the only function inside of it. I want to call this funktion inside of the main.py

Comment: So mat_import includes only the function matread()? What do you get when you run dir(mi) or help(mi) in main.py?

Comment: @Jonas The help(mi) and dir(mi) shows correctly insode of main.py.

Comment: When you say 'correctly' what do you mean? Does the output of dir(mi) include 'matread' in that list? I understand you can't post some of your code here, but if you're going to continue being this vague it's going to be very difficult to help resolve this.

Comment: @Jonas I'm sorry about this. matread is included in the dir(mi) list. I will edit the code of mat_import in the question now. Just a second please.

Comment: Ok I see your updated code. Try adding the empty parentheses after matread in main.py -> mi.matread() @Rainer

Comment: @Jonas This didn't work. I still get "AttributeError: module 'mat_import' has no attribute 'matread'" and can't figure out why.

Comment: Hmm, I'm afraid I can't help you any further then. If the list dir(mi) includes 'matread', then calling mi.matread() shouldn't give an AttributeError. Check spellings/typos?

Comment: @Jonas I will check for spellings/typos again. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I figured it out. The import of main.py in mat_read and an indent in mat_import caused the error.